# PHP json_decode returning null

Tags: php, utf-8, json

I searched a lot in google and stackoverflow, but couldn't find a solution.

I've the following json coming from DB:

```
{"nome":"Tést","curso":"Educação Infantil","serie":"1ª Etapa 1011"}
```

As you can see, there are some utf8 chars that were not saved as unicode.
And when I try to decode this json, it returns **null** and json_last_error returns **5**.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Error 5 is `JSON_ERROR_UTF8`. I think you need to format the character `ª` some other way (if at all possible).

Comment: Which version of php do you use?

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.3.3-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like following. Use with single quote;

```
$a = '{"nome":"Tést","curso":"Educação Infantil","serie":"1ª Etapa 1011"}';
var_dump(json_decode($a));
```

Here is working demo: **[codepad](http://codepad.org/x9zDpK5V)**

If not work, alternatively you can use [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) to convert your stirng to utf-8 and decode like;

```
<?php
$a = '{"nome":"Tést","curso":"Educação Infantil","serie":"1ª Etapa 1011"}';
$a = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($a));
$json = json_decode($a);
var_dump($json);
?>
```

Comment: @RakeshSharma how? I have provided demo. Is not working demo for you?

Comment: Could you try updated code if you have iconv installed?

Comment: ignoring utf8 it worked too! thanks!!! I chose the other answer because was way simpler! :P

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$utfstr= mb_convert_encoding($str ,"UTF-8");
$output = json_decode($utfstr, true);
```